# Reprojecting shape data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, json, epsg

My json data is not projecting correctly. The shape should be in Mali. Can anyone explain how to adjust the projection?

```
[
  {
    "Country": "Mali",
    "Layer": "Industrial",
    "CRS": "",
    "LicenseType": "exploration authorization",
    "Owner": "****é SARL",
    "DateApplied": "2017-10-20T00:00:00.000Z",
    "DateGranted": "2017-11-15T00:00:00.000Z",
    "ExpiryDate": "2018-02-15T00:00:00.000Z",
    "Status": "expired",
    "GeometricData": [
      [
        [
          15.1886111111,
          -11.7547222222
        ],
        [
          15.1886111111,
          -11.6597222222
        ],
        [
          15.085555555555,
          -11.6597222222
        ],
        [
          15.085555555555,
          -11.7175
        ],
        [
          15.145,
          -11.7175
        ],
        [
          15.145,
          -11.7425
        ],
        [
          15.1588888889,
          -11.7425
        ],
        [
          15.1588888889,
          -11.7547222222
        ]
      ]
    ],
    "Commodity": [
      "or"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Country": "Mali",
    "Layer": "Industrial",
    "CRS": "",
    "LicenseType": "exploration authorization",
    "Owner": "testSARL",
    "DateApplied": "2017-10-20T00:00:00.000Z",
    "DateGranted": "2017-11-15T00:00:00.000Z",
    "ExpiryDate": "2018-02-15T00:00:00.000Z",
    "Status": "expired",
    "GeometricData": [
      [
        [
          10.7886111111,
          -6.489444444445
        ],
        [
          10.7886111111,
          -6.4261111111
        ],
        [
          10.76,
          -6.4261111111
        ],
        [
          10.76,
          -6.4591666667
        ],
        [
          10.7097222222,
          -6.4591666667
        ],
        [
          10.7097222222,
          -6.489444444445
        ]
      ]
    ],
    "Commodity": [
      "or"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: More information please on your data set. What do you have? Can you post a link to your data? (WeTransfer, DropBox, etc)

Comment: Well the [1st point](https://goo.gl/maps/kFaF5bn5Fo6nNTN19) is in Mali. Is the problem that the data in a geographic (lat, lon) projection or is it that the data is json but not a standard spatial format?

Comment: @pointdump These are two data points from around 500, they are all formatted the same. I'm using a Python script to import them alongside 20 other data sets, a few of which are projecting wrong. 

You're right when using Google to check the point it appears in Mali. but when I import the point to QGIS it shows up in the Atlantic. How do I adjust this to use QGIS to reproject the points in Mali?

Comment: Your points are Latitude, Longitude, and both sets land in Mali nicely. Longitude, Latitude puts them in the ocean.

Comment: Latitude= Y and Longitude = X. You may need to reverse the coords to from lat, lon to lon, lat in your code

Comment: Thank you, that is extremely useful.  What CRS are you using to land them in Mali?

Comment: EPSG:4326 works.

Comment: fantastic. I changed the CRS to ESPG:4326 and used the QGIS Processing tools - Swap X and Y coordinates and the data projects correctly. Thank you!